# What is the difference between vdso32 amd vdsox32?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, shared-libraries, vdso

I apologize if the answer to this question is apparent, but why are there two versions<sup>[1]</sup> of the vdso for 32-bit executables on linux systems, and what is the criteria used to select among them?

<sub>* as can be found in `/lib/modules/KERNEL_NAME/vdso`</sub>

Comment: x32 is [a Linux ABI](https://sites.google.com/site/x32abi/) which is kind of a mix between x86 and x64. It uses 32-bit address size but runs in full 64-bit mode, including all 64-bit instructions and registers available.

Comment: That seems to be it! It seems that standard x86_64 kernels now support three ABIs. Please repost your comment as an answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

x32 is a [Linux ABI](https://sites.google.com/site/x32abi/) which is kind of a mix between x86 and x64. It uses 32-bit address size but runs in full 64-bit mode, including all 64-bit instructions and registers available.